# Unable to resolve service for type 'BackEnd.Models.UserContext'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am new in .NET Core applications and I try to create an app with angulare and .NET Core but when I want to add identity in my application I encounter with this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'BackEnd.Models.UserContext' while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,BackEnd.Models.UserContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.

Here is my code:

```
namespace BackEnd.Models
{
    public class UserContext: IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public UserContext()
        {

        }

        public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options): base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                   .Build();
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnectionString");
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Start up

```
namespace BackEnd
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().Build();
                });
            });

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors("EnableCORS");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to call `AddDbContext<T>`? P.S. Building `new ConfigurationBuilder()` inside your `OnConfiguring` is bad, its sync api, the json file will be called on every resolve (means on every request if your Context is scoped which is the default. Why not just set the provider inside `services.AddDbContext<T>(config => ... )`? You get the configuration builder there already, see [Using DbContext with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss to add default token provider ? 
change like this.

```
namespace BackEnd.Models
{
    // Add IdentityRole
    public class UserContext: IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>
    {
        public UserContext()
        {

        }
      ...
}
```

and this .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); missing

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

       ...

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>()
                 // Here is missing
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();;
    }
```

Add app.UseAuthentication(); after cors

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("EnableCORS");
        //add this
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```